# Automate the download of the MP3 version of a show from a subscription-based RSS

Tags: windows, html, automation, scraping, rss

I subscribe to a news site that frequently publish a page with a show in an enbeded video (the show) and a link to the MP3 of the show. The page is available to anyone but you need a valid subscription to see the video and download the MP3.

New shows are published on a public RSS flux with a link to the show page.

I have of course a subscription to the show.

I was wondering **what collection of plugins/tools I should use** to:

1. Trigger the script when there is a RSS publication
2. Connect to the page through my browser already logged on the website. (Maybe Selenium?)
3. Download the MP3 link (the `<a>` tag for the MP3 always use the same class).

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you talking about a video podcast ? Cause what you describe very precisely looks like a video podcast ...

Comment: They don't have per-subscriber RSS feeds? For several things I listen to, they have subscriber-only RSS feeds, which I can then pick up with desktop rss feed reader.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a couple of [python](https://www.python.org) libraries working together:

- [RSS Feed Parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) for which the example [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/feedparser/using-feedparser-in-python) may be very useful
- [youtube-dl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/youtube_dl) supports 1000s of services and can download the videos & audio file from them including posting a username & password, etc. if your news site is a popular one it is probably supported *or if that is not working for the service you are using*
- [Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize) can act like a browser, including cookies, etc., and can pretend to be a number of browser types *or any of a number of other python web client libraries*

Your python script could query the RSS feed to check for new posts and if there are any connect to the web server, log on and download the Video &/or MP3 file(s).